# Biophysics PhD after Master's in Computational Biology. Is it a common path?

Tags: phd, masters, physics

I am doing my masters in computational life sciences. My fascination with the topic started with how physics elegantly explains the biological systems. More I am digging into the subjects, more I feel more gravitated towards the field of biophysics. (I do feel very repulsive for when anyone starts talking about AL/ML/Databases, Maybe that's just a contrarian part of me :/ )

I have invested a lot of time taking classes (mostly online) in dynamical systems, statistical mechanics and quantum mechanics. I have chosen most of the courses in biochemistry and theoretical biophysics domain(with compulsory courses in computational biology which is almost half of my master course). Do you think it will be an easy path to get into biophysics PhD?

Also, will the research I do during my thesis will matter more than the courses I have taken during my masters?

Comment: It might make a difference in different countries. Knowing a location might help folks give an answer.

Comment: I am pursuing my master's in Germany at TU Dresden. I am okay with applying at any country/university after my masters as long as the work will be good :)

Comment: Welcome to academia.SE. We prefer one question per question, and general sharing of experiences does not suit the site format well. Could you edit the question to be more focused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering strictly to you questions:

1- Do you think it will be an easy path to get into biophysics PhD?
Yes. You only need to argument your research as multi-field with an holistic approach, base your methods or the relation on technology and how it impacts the new field,  or propose some innovative way to apply or relate computational sciences  to biological systems (neural networks or Ai to learn how X works are always a good hit.)

As as example, my first career was in 'environmental improvement and diagnostics', then I went into 'informatique sciences' , specialization MBA into 'economy', then MBA into ' Computational Systems' but PHD in 'Organizations direction/Management'. It all comes down on how you relate everything.

2- Will the research I do during my thesis will matter more than the courses I have taken during my masters?

If you can, avoid a thesis at all costs. But if you need to do it.. then yes, it will matter more than everything else, in fact, besides publications, the thesis might as well be the only thing that will count for academia and for your current PHD (In this century its more of an ego thing and the 'I did it so I expect you to suffer it too' mentality, regardless of all your knowledge or advancements in other fields).